# How Can I display points instead of password with reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, passwords, hide

actually I want to display the users from my db in a table..I have a password that I want to display points instead of it..anyone could help me doing this?
this how I display the password

```
      <td> <Lock size={14} color=" #273746 " /> &nbsp; {item.password}</td>
```

I would be very thankful if anyone of you can help mee

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a string of asterisks with the same length as the original string (e.g. `item.password`), then you can utilize the `String.prototype.repeat` method:

```
"*".repeat("mysecretpassword".length); // "****************"
```

However, I would advise showing a constant number of asterisks not related to the passwords because it is significantly easier to hack a password if a malicious person knew the number of characters was in it by counting the asterisks if they had, for example, taken a picture of the hidden passwords list.  Therefore, I think you're best bet would be to just hard code a certain number of asterisks and show it for all of the passwords:

```
"**********"
```

Comment: you don't know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

answers above look correct but I just need to remember you that you shouldn't ever get text/plain passwords from your API. further, you shouldn't keep passwords in text/plain on database. if you really need to keep them in text/plain form, you already need to mask them on back-end before sending them to the client (front-end).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Javascript string replace function.
You can find it here :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

{item.password.replace({item.password}, "**********")}

Comment: it's ok thanks @Yanis

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).